# Placing images left and right of each other

Tags: positioning, minipage

I want to create the following layout:

```
 ------------                                                                  -------------
|   IMAGE 1  |                                                                |   IMAGE 2   |
|____________|                                                                |_____________|
```

Notice that the two images are relatively small in size, but I want them to be placed at the right/leftmost edge of the document. I tried it using minipages like this:

```
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{image1.eps}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{4cm}
    \begin{flushright}
        \includegraphics[width=4cm]{image2.eps}
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

But then, the two images are placed like this:

```
 ------------
|   IMAGE 1  |
|____________|

 -------------
|   IMAGE 2   |
|_____________|
```

I fooled around with the values of minipage and image-width, but nothing seems to help...

Edit: Also, I need the images to be centered to each other (horizontally speaking), so they are nicely aligned if one is bigger than the other.

Comment: What happens if you do `\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image1.eps}\hfill\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image2.eps}`?

Comment: (Incidentally, the `flushright` does nothing because it is _inside_ the `minipage`, and your `minipage` and graphic are the same size.  That the two are on separate lines is caused by the blank line between the `minipage` environments: that starts a new paragraph.)

Comment: The empty line between the `minipage`s is inserting a new paragraph which make the second image be placed below the first. You need to avoid this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `\hfill` to add a horizontal filler between both images. This will push the second image to the right. You need to watch empty lines here because they create new paragraphs. You should add a new paragraph before and after both images, but not between them. In the example code I added explicit `\par`s to highlight this, but implicit ones i.e. empty lines are fine, too.

You can vertical center both images using `\raisebox`. Images included with `\includegraphics` only have a height but no (=zero) depth. Every box (character, image, ...) in (La)TeX has a height, width and depth. Everything below the baseline (the invisible line the letters are placed on) is part of the depth. The `\raisebox` command allows you to raise or lower its content but also to set the official width and height of it which can be larger or smaller than the original, the *natural* amount. The original height can be accessed by the `\height` length. Use `\raisebox{-.5\height}` to lower the images half under the baseline. This will effectively center them vertically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% For example text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\par
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image1}}%
\hfill
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image2}}%
\par

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

You could also put the above code into `\makebox[\textwidth]{...}` to ensure they are on one line if you don't like the `\par`s.

---

This can simplified by using the `adjustbox` package. There the key `valign=M` (or `raise=-0.5\height`) can be used. The `margin` key could also be added to improve the spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% For example text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\par
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=4cm,valign=M,margin=0ex 2ex]{example-image-a}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=4cm,valign=M,margin=0ex 2ex]{example-image-b}%
\par

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: nice. I'd forgotten about `\height`.

Comment: @ApoY2k: I meant to use `\makebox` with `\raisebox`: `\makebox[\textwidth]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image1}}\hfill
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image2}}}%`, just to ensure both are on one line. Using paragraph breaks around it achieves the same.

Comment: This also works well if you want to have text next to an image.

Answer (score 7):

How about this?

```
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image1.eps}
\hspace{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image2.eps}
```

`\hspace{\fill}` uses up all available space, pushing your images to the margins.

You can adjust the vertical alignment using `minipages`, so your original example would become something like this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[c]{4cm}
\framebox{ABC \rule{1pt}{1cm}}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}[c]{4cm}
\framebox{DEF \rule{1pt}{10cm} }
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

More details on this can be found in [epslatex.pdf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epslatex)

Comment: That works nicely, but now there's a second problem; the second image is now aligned to the bottomline of the first - how can I get it to align to the center (horizontally speaking)

Comment: You might write a line about what `\hspace` and `\hfill` commands, that will make your answer even better.

Comment: I would just write `\hfill` instead.

Comment: @ApoY2k: You should update your question with the vertical alignment requirement.