# How to move this minipage 0.2 cm to right?

Tags: minipage

I find methods to align the vertical alignment but not the horizontal. 
Code

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}   

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88624/13173
\newsavebox{\fminipagebox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{fminipage}{m O{\fboxsep}}
 {\par\kern#2\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\fminipagebox}
  \begin{minipage}{#1}\ignorespaces}
 {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \makebox[#1]{%
    \kern\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax
    \fbox{\usebox{\fminipagebox}}%
    \kern\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax
  }\par\kern#2
 }

\begin{document}       
\begin{fminipage}{16em}%\textwidth}
{\small
Seller: \textbf{Student A. Masi} \\
\\
Date: 30.9.2016 \\
Local food store 
}
\end{fminipage}
\end{document}
```

Methods unsuccessfuly tested

- With `raisebox` and `hfill`

  ```
  % http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16937/13173
  % these not working when applied with \width etc:
  %\raisebox{-.5\height}
  %\hfill
  ```

OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Texlive: 2016
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA

Comment: Since the example only contains the `fminipage`, I can't understand what alignment you're referring to. And what 2px should mean?

Comment: Pixel means nothing in PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple modification (the code in the answer you refer to was meant to make the box's borders stick in the margin):

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{xparse}

% load showframe just to show where the box borders are
\usepackage{showframe}

\newsavebox{\fminipagebox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{fminipage}{m O{\fboxsep}}
 {\par\kern#2\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\fminipagebox}
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}\ignorespaces}
 {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \fbox{\usebox{\fminipagebox}}%
  \par\kern#2 }

\begin{document}       
\begin{fminipage}{16em}
\small
Seller: \textbf{Student A. Masi}

\bigskip

Date: 30.9.2016 \\
Local food store 
\end{fminipage}

\begin{fminipage}{\textwidth}
\small
Seller: \textbf{Student A. Masi}

\bigskip

Date: 30.9.2016 \\
Local food store 
\end{fminipage}

\end{document}
```

Output with `showframe`

[image]

Output without `showframe`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, but it works....

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{xparse}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88624/13173
\newsavebox{\fminipagebox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{fminipage}{m O{\fboxsep}}
 {\par\kern#2\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\fminipagebox}
  \begin{minipage}{#1}\ignorespaces}
 {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \makebox[#1]{%
    \kern\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax
    \fbox{\usebox{\fminipagebox}}%
    \kern\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax
  }\par\kern#2
 }
\newsavebox{\ugh}


\begin{document}       
\begin{fminipage}{16em}%\textwidth}
{\small
Seller: \textbf{Student A. Masi} \\
\\
Date: 30.9.2016 \\
Local food store 
}
\end{fminipage}

\savebox{\ugh}{%
\begin{fminipage}{16em}%\textwidth}
    {\small
        Seller: \textbf{Student A. Masi} \\
        \\
        Date: 30.9.2016 \\
        Local food store 
    }
\end{fminipage}}

\noindent\hspace*{0mm}\usebox{\ugh}

\begin{minipage}{16em}
    {\small
        Seller: \textbf{Student A. Masi} \\
        \\
        Date: 30.9.2016 \\
        Local food store 
    }
\end{minipage}

\hspace{2mm}\begin{minipage}{16em}
    {\small
        Seller: \textbf{Student A. Masi} \\
        \\
        Date: 30.9.2016 \\
        Local food store 
    }
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which of those proposals do you propose mostly?

Comment: The first is the original.  The savebox business just creates a savebox which can be moved left or right, so the lines from savebox through usebox is what you need plus the newsavebox command in the preamble.