# Split images with text in between

Tags: beamer, graphics, presentations

I want to make the front page of my presentation in such a way that two images at the right-most and let-most positions of the page with couple of lines of text in the middle. Any help is much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\title{Presentation Title}

\subtitle{Optional Subtitle}

\author{F.~Author\inst{1} \and S.~Another\inst{2}}

\institute[Universities of Somewhere and Elsewhere] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
  \inst{1}%
  Department of Computer Science\\
  University of Somewhere
  \and
  \inst{2}%
  Department of Theoretical Philosophy\\
  University of Elsewhere}

\date{Conference Name, 2013}

\subject{Theoretical Computer Science}
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post some code you've tried?

Comment: This post helped to get an idea: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16937/placing-images-left-and-right-of-each-other

But the front page doesn't appear withing \begin{document} ..... \end{document}, so it wasn't quite work out.

Comment: Don't you have some code for your front page? Which class of document do you use? `beamer`? We can't create everything *ex nihilo*.

Comment: I've included the code of the template I'm using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\title{Presentation Title}

\subtitle{Optional Subtitle}

\author{F.~Author\inst{1} \and S.~Another\inst{2}}

\institute[Universities of Somewhere and Elsewhere] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
  \inst{1}%
  Department of Computer Science\\
  University of Somewhere
  \and
  \inst{2}%
  Department of Theoretical Philosophy\\
  University of Elsewhere}

\date{Conference Name, 2013}

\subject{Theoretical Computer Science}
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage

  \adjustimage{height=22mm, valign=c, raise=-2.4ex}{BugsBunny}\hfill \parbox[t]{40mm}{Two stars from the Warner Bros Cartoons Department}\hfill \adjustimage{height=22mm, valign=c, raise=-2.4ex}{TasmanianDevil}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'll adjust it the way I want. One small question,  once I do what you've mentioned here, I get another slide similar to what I had before without the two images. Do you know what's the reason ? Thank you.

Comment: No idea *a priori*. With the very same code and nothing else?

Comment: With the same code. It's all right. I'll see.

Comment: I obtain only one frame.